# Google Cloud Engine with OpenVPN Server

Tags: google-compute-engine, openvpn

Hello Stack Community,

I'm facing weird behavior of OpenVPN.
I'm running a OpenVPN Server on a Google Compute Engine with a Database. I would like to achive, to connect with a client via OpenVPN to the Google Compute Engine and insert data into the database. 
If I'm connected to my home network everything works properly, I run OpenVPN Client as admin, get a secure connection within seconds and insert data into the database. Now the weird behavior. I'm at my parents place and using their network and my OpenVPN Client is not able to connect to my Google Compute Engine. OpenVPN Client run as admin and OpenVPN Server running on Google Cumpute Engine.
So I changed the network for the third time and I was again able to connect to my Google Compute Engine via OpenVPN.

Any Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This issue isn't related to GCE because connection works from other places. You should reach to ISP (at your parents place) with this question. Some ISPs block VPN traffic.

Comment: With have the same Internet service provider (isp)

Comment: You can check logs at OpenVPN server side. If there aren't any records about connections you should ask your ISP, if you found any errors you can investigate further.

Comment: Did you Add a firewall rule to allow all traffic on port 1194 UDP (default): `0.0.0.0/0` for the Network Interface?